# Get values from one df and store into another df and assign the values to new column names for each row simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to get data from one dataframe using for example, loc, based on a condition and if true, retrieving more than one value (I.e. from different columns) in that row and append them to another dataframe in a new row (e.g. location: index+1) but storing each value in a column different than the original dataframe’s column names. And without using loops.

I originally did accomplished this by looping through the dataframe and appending the desired data to the new dataframe, but I can't use a loop.

What I have:

```
data.columns = […,"Age", …., "Pclass"] # columns needed: "Age" and "Pclass"
pas12to19.columns = ["AGE_12", "AGE_TEEN", "PCLASS"]
```

Add ages 12 to new df and ages 13-19 to new df

```
df12 = data.loc[((data['Age'] == 12)), ['Age', 'Pclass']]
df13to19 = data.loc[((data['Age'] < 20) & (data['Age'] > 12)), ['Age', 'Pclass']]
```

store in pas12to19 df

```
pas12to19 = pas12to19.append(df12)
pas12to19 = pas12to19.append(df13to19)
```

This method adds the column names from the original dataframe to the new dataframe. 
I would then need to filter over `pas12to19` dataframe and move the values in one column to their appropriate column then delete the columns `Age` and `Pclass` that came from the original dataframe. I would think there is a better approach.

What I would like to do (but isn't allowed):

`pas12to19["AGE_TEEN", "PCLASS"] = data.loc[((data['Age'] < 20) & (data['Age'] > 12)), ['Age', 'Pclass']]`

I.e. Store `Age` in `AGE_TEEN` and store `Pclass` in `PCLASS`.

Original df table `Data`

```
... Pclass Age ...
    3      17
    1      15
    3      13
    1      19
    2      15
```

New and expected df table `pas12to19`

```
    AGE_12 AGE_TEEN PCLASS
    NaN    17       3
    NaN    15       1
    NaN    13       2
    12     NaN      1
    NaN    15       1
```

Comment: kindly post a sample dataframe, with expected output. no pics. data only

Comment: Good idea. Thanks

Comment: The original data df (from a titanic dataset) has ages 0.6 to 100. I need passengers 12 up to and including 19, stored into the new dataset df12to19.

Comment: i probably i'm getting the info mixed up somewhere; however, if all you need is to extract the ages from 12 to 19, you could use pandas between ... df.loc[df.Age.between(12,19)]

Comment: I could use 'between' and only extract the columns Age and Pclass but it adds those columns to the new df. Instead, I would like to store the values from Age (and Pclass) into an existing column in the new df. And if possible store the values from Age and Pclass simultaneously together in the same row.

Comment: Also, no problem. Ambiguity seems to be so common in data science, so please ask any questions you need.

Comment: ok. sure. post ur original dataframe, post the dataframe u want to pull the age and pclass from, then show ur final dataframe, and pls point out the change in the final dataframe.

Comment: The original df `data` is the df I want to pull from. The receiving df is `pas12to19`. Both are displayed in the question above.